# Bounty on community wiki questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[How to write a network game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/249/how-to-write-a-network-game) was converted to a wiki, but the bounty wasn't removed. Bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> Bounties are not affected by community
>   wiki mode. When you award a bounty to
>   an answer marked as community wiki,
>   the reputation bonus will still be
>   awarded.